# segmentation fault when manipulating strings?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

this peace of code summarizes the problem that I have.i want to copy a file from a source to a specified destination which i'm allowed to change it's name it's a function that's integrated in an application i'm trying to create that manages files

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void concatenate_string(char *original, char *add)
{
   while(*original!='\0')
     original++;

   while(*add!='\0')
     {
        *original = *add;
         add++;
         original++;
     }
     *original = '\0';
}

 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {

    char *nom;
    char *path;
    printf("entrer a name \n");
    scanf("%s",nom);
    printf("entrer a pathh \n");
    scanf("%s",pathh);
    char *dest=(char*)malloc(strlen(nomm)+46+1);
    strcat(dest,"/home/ridaamine/Desktop/app/application/Files/");
    strcat(dest,nom);
    char *comand=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+8+strlen(path)+1);
    strcat(comand,"cp -via ");
    strcat(comand,path);
    strcat(comand," ");
    strcat(comand,name);
    system(comand);
  }
```

Comment: You won't succeed with `strcat(dest,"...");` because the string `dest` has not been initialised to the empty string. The sequence should be `malloc(...); strcpy(...); strcat(...)`. Ditto with `comand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't  initialize `nom`

```
scanf("%s",nom);
```

either

```
nom = malloc(SOME_SIZE);
```

and then, let's say `SOME_SIZE == 100`

```
scanf("%99s", nom);
```

or

```
char nom[SOME_SIZE];
```

and then, also let's say `SOME_SIZE == 100`

```
scanf("%99s", nom);
```

and of course the same applies to `path`.

The second solution is better because it's faster `not that much` and you don't need to `free(nom)` after using it. The second case could be needed in the rare case where the size of the string is so large (> 8M) it would overflow the stack.

And as ***`Weather Vane`*** points out `strcat` has a problem too you should use `strcpy` the first time

```
strcat(dest,"/home/ridaamine/Desktop/app/application/Files/");
strcat(dest,nom);
```

shoul be

```
strcpy(dest,"/home/ridaamine/Desktop/app/application/Files/");
strcat(dest,nom);
```

and clearly this time, the same applies to `command`.

Finally you have a space that you didn't count in

```
malloc(strlen(dest) + 8 + strlen(path) + 1 + 1 /* space " " */)
```

**Tip**: you don't need to cast `malloc` so don't, it could hide a potential bug. And always check that `malloc` didn't return `NULL`, before dereferencing the pointer.

You should call free after you are done too, this is your own code fixed

```
 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {

    char nom[100];
    char path[100];
    char _path[] = "/home/ridaamine/Desktop/app/application/Files/";
    char cp[] = "cp -via ";
    char space[] = " ";

    printf("entrer a name \n");
    scanf("%99s", nom);
    printf("entrer a path \n");
    scanf("%99s", path);

    char *dest = malloc(strlen(nom) + strlen(_path) + 1);
    if (dest == NULL)
    {
        printf("no more memory left.\n");
        return -1;
    }       
    strcpy(dest, _path);
    strcat(dest, nom);

    char *comand = malloc(strlen(dest) + strlen(cp) + strlen(space) + strlen(path) + 1);
    if (command == NULL)
    {
        free(dest);
        printf("no more memory left.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(comand, cp);

    strcat(comand, path);
    strcat(comand, space);
    strcat(comand, dest);

    free(dest);
    system(comand);
    free(command);

    return 0; // always return from main
  }
```

Comment: i tried the second one it worked but i still have a problem when it finished and sends the command to the system i get a segmentation fault

Comment: Make sure the string lengths are plenty adeqaute - don't be mean with memory unless you are on embedded platform.

Comment: how much would you suggest i mean if i allocate 50 does that mean that i can store 50 characters or what because i think it's more then sufficient

Comment: The first string `dest` only allocated enough memory for the pathname, so it will break on your second `strcat()`. Why not double what you think it will need - even better add up the string lengths instead of hard-coding.

Comment: i changed the code and i allocated strlen(nom)+200 and for command i allocated +900 but still it gives me seg fault just now that it crashes after the program ends should i free command and name or what ?

Comment: @RidaAmine try printing `dest` and `comand` and commenting out `system(comand)`. And BTW what was `dest` for anyway?

Comment: @RidaAmine, don't allocate more than the needed memory, that could hide a bug. Just check my answer update, `strcat` a " " which you don't count.

Comment: Thanks Guys a lot it worked in my project , you can't imagine how happy I'am thanks thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first `strcat()` must in each case be changed to `strcpy()` because the strings have not been initialised to the empty string. And the first string `dest` will certainly be too short.

```
char *dest=(char*)malloc(strlen(nomm)+46+1);    // this is too short
strcpy(dest,"/home/ridaamine/Desktop/app/application/Files/");
strcat(dest,nom);

char *comand=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+8+strlen(path)+1);
strcpy(comand,"cp -via ");
strcat(comand,path);
strcat(comand," ");
```

Comment: @iharob it's not very good form taking people's comments and putting them in your answer.

Comment: It's not that bad, you could have posted the answer first and I would not take it from you, but you make me think the answer is Ok but I just missed that, notice that the first problem I mention happens first and I didn't yet reach that part when I wrote the answer, still I admit that your comment made me see that faster. You can find comments from me to answers that help increase the quality of the answer itself, sometimes I have an answer to the same question, I also have edits that improve answers to questions I've also answered.

Comment: I think, that's what comments are for. I give +1 for your answer, you did spot a problem, but not all of them.

Comment: That's true but this is another of those occasions where you have rushed to get in the first answer and then added more and more content.

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't mention what you already said. I upvoted @iharob's correct answer.

Comment: It will be Ok for me if you do mention that.